# iOS 14 Crash on reordering UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-access, reorderlist

I have a strange issue in using the reorder feature in my app. I am using **.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition** method for reordering Cell.
It is workin on iOS 11, iOS 12, iOS 13 but crashing on **iOS 14 beta** version.

*Is there any implementation or how can I fix that?*

```
  @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
      switch(gesture.state) {
      case .began:
          guard let selectedIndexPath = reorderCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: reorderCollectionView)) else {
              break
          }
          reorderCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
      case .changed:
          reorderCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: reorderCollectionView))
      case .ended:
          reorderCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
      default:
          reorderCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
      }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: There is no any crash log , only bad access.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with creating UICollectionView programmatically,
This may be a bug from the iOS 14 Beta

```
private let pragmaticallyCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 343, height: 84)
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return collectionView
  }()
```